# Any map from $X \to {(S^1 )}^k$ induces a 0 map on reduced homology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $X$ be a simply connected space. Prove that any map from $X \to {(S^1 )}^k$ induces a 0 map on reduced homology.

My attempt:

Let $f :  X \to {(S^1 )}^k$ be a map. $X$  simply connected implies that $\pi_1 (X)=0$ and thus consider the Universal cover of ${(S^1 )}^k$ , $p : \Bbb R^k \to {(S^1 )}^k$ then , $0=f_*(\pi_1 (X)) \subseteq p_*(\pi_1(\Bbb R^k))=0$ . So by General lifting lemma, $f$ admits a unique lift $\tilde{f}:X \to \Bbb R^k$ , since $\Bbb R^k$ is contractible we get that  $\tilde{f}$ is null-homotpoic and thus $f=p \circ \tilde{f}$ is  homotopic to constant, thus the induced map on homology is $0$ and thus the induced map is $0$ also on the reduced homology.

Please point out mistakes, if any!

Comment: Perhaps instead of saying "$f=p \circ \bar{f}$ is constant" you should say "homotopic to a constant map". Also, a constant map does not induce the zero map on homology in the zeroth degree, but when you reduced it must be the zero map. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yeah, thanks that's what I meant to say! Anythinh else you would like to point out?

Comment: See my edit to my comment.

Comment: So you know that zeroth homology is the free abelian group generated by the path components? Imagine that we are computing the induced map of $* \rightarrow *$, then since it is the identity it should induce the identity on $H_0(*)$. As well, it is homotopic to a constant since it is constant. But the identity on $H_0(*)=\mathbb{Z}$ is not the zero map, so we know that maps homotopic to constant maps don't induce the zero map on $H_0$.

Comment: Have you given an argument in class as to why it induces 0 on homology groups higher than 0?