# Prove that any map $T → T$ ($T$ = Torus) whose restriction to $S^1 ∨ S^1$ is null-homotopic induces a $0$ map on reduced homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Prove that any map $T → T$ ($T$ = Torus) whose restriction to $S^1 ∨ S^1$ is null-homotopic induces a $0$ map on reduced homology.

A few informations which I know :

(1) $T$ is obtained by attaching a 2-cell to it's 1-skeleton $S^1 ∨ S^1$ and thus $T / S^1 ∨ S^1 \simeq S^2$ .

(2) The quotient map $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^2$ collapsing the subspace $S^1 ∨ S^1$ to a point is not null homotopic and it induces an isomorphism on $H_2$ .

(3) Any map $S^2 \to S^1 \times S^1$ is null homotopic.

(4) [Let $X$ be a simply connected space. Aany map from $X \to {(S^1 )}^k$ induces a 0 map on reduced homology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191252/any-map-from-x-to-s1-k-induces-a-0-map-on-reduced-homology)

Can I use these to come up with something? I have no idea! I get really confused when the problem asks to find the effect of some map on the homology.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You can check that in fact any map $S^2\rightarrow S^1\vee S^1$ is null-homotopic, which you can do by finding the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$. Since $S^1\vee S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^1$ is a cofibration, your map in question must factor up to homotopy through $q$. Put these facts together and you have your claim.

Comment: @Tyrone Can you kindly give a detailed answer to my question ? I really have no idea whatsoever regrading this problem.

Comment: Another approach is to show it induces the $0$ map on cohomology because the cohomology ring is generated by the two degree $1$ cohomology classes. Then show that a map which is $0$ on cohomology has to be $0$ on homology.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to look at the 1st and 2nd homology groups.

For the first you have the sequence $$S^1\lor S^1\rightarrow T  \rightarrow T$$
This composition is null-homotopic . So at the level of homology we have

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_1(S^1\lor S^1)@>{i_*}>> H_1(T) @>{f_*}>> 
H_1(T)
\end{CD}
$$
 the composition is $0$.

However we know $
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_1(S^1\lor S^1)@>{i_*}>> H_1(T)
\end{CD}
$ is an isomorphism (you can see this from cellular homology ) and hence $$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ H_1(T) @>{f_*}>> 
H_1(T)
\end{CD}
$$ is the $0$ map.
However you will run into problem at the $2$nd homology group if you try via this kind of argument.

So we approach as follows.

Now $(T, S^1\lor S^1)$ satisfy the Homotopy Extension Property. So if you have a map $$f: T\rightarrow T$$ and a homotopy $$H : S^1\lor S^1 \times [0,1] \rightarrow T$$ between $f|_{S^1\lor S^1}$ and $constant \ map$ you can extend this to get a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ where $g|_{S^1\lor S^1}$ is constant. Moreover $f_*=g_*$ by homotopy invariance property of homology.

Now by universal property of quotient topology $g$ factors through $$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T@>{q}>>T/S^1\lor S^1\cong S^2 @>{\bar g}>> 
T
\end{CD}
$$

Now look at $\bar g:S^2\rightarrow T$. By general lifting lemma you can lift this to get a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^2@>{\tilde {\bar g}}>> \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\\
@VV{id}V @VV{p \ \ \ \ \ \ covering \ \ \  map}V \\
S^2 @>{\bar g}>> T
\end{CD}
$$

Since $\mathbb R^2$ is contractible $\bar g$ is nullhomotopic and hence $\bar g_*=0$

So $g_*=\bar g_*q_*=0$
As such $f_*=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $f:T\to T$ is nullhomotopic when restricted to $S^1\vee S^1$ then since the inclusion $S^1\vee S^1\to T$ is a cofibration (the inclusion of a skeleton in a CW-complex), you can extend that homotopy to $T$ and thus in fact assume that $f$ is constant on $S^1\vee S^1$.

It follows that it factors through $T/(S^1\vee S^1)\simeq S^2$.

Now, as Tyrone suggests, we may look at the universal cover of $S^1\times S^1$, which is just  $\mathbb R^2$, hence a contractible space : its $\pi_2$ is trivial and therefore so is $\pi_2(S^1\times S^1)$ : in particular a map $S^2\to S^1\times S^1$ is nullhomotopic, therefore must induce $0$ on homology : so must the original map.